# How to display characters read from a file using getc()

Tags: c, file, getc

When I try to read input from a file named "file1", my program correctly displays
the number of characters in the file, but in an unrecognized character format.
Below is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void db_sp(FILE*);

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{   
    FILE *ifp,*ofp;

    if(argc!=2) {
      fprintf(stderr,"Program execution form: %s infile\n",argv[0]);
      exit(1);
    }
    ifp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if (ifp==NULL) printf("sdaf");
    //ofp=fopen(argv[2],"w+") ; 
    db_sp(ifp);
    fclose(ifp);
    //fclose(ofp);
    return 0;
}

void db_sp(FILE *ifp)
{     
    char c;
    while(c=getc(ifp) !=EOF) {
      //printf("%c",c);
      putc(c,stdout);
      if(c=='\n' || c=='\t' || c==' ')
        printf("%c",c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code in your question.

Comment: Can you show what your file contains? What does your prinft print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
while(c=getc(ifp) !=EOF){
```

Because of [operator precendence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), this `getc(ifp) !=EOF` gets executed first. Then `c = <result of comparison>` gets executed. Which is not the order you want.

Use parentheses to force the correct order.

```
while((c=getc(ifp)) !=EOF) {
```

Other notes:
`getc` returns an `int` so you should change the type of `c` to `int`.
Also, if you fail to open the file, you still continue execution. You should gracefully exit on failure.

Comment: And change `char c;` to `int c;` which is the type returned by `getc()` and required by `putc()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane True. Updated.

Comment: @AjeyaSiddhartha for what it's worth `'\n'` is also of type `int`.

Comment: The reason for getc to return an int and not a char, is that `'\xff'` is a valid character and shall not be misinterpreted as an eond of file.